# Idiom for: managing to solve a big problem only to be frustrated by a smaller problem

Tags: idioms, british-english, idiom-requests

What would be an idiom for solving a massive problem and then only getting hindered by a small problem?

So after solving a hard problem, getting stopped by the easy problem.

It would not be: out of the frying pan (and) into the fire. Because it means: from a bad situation to a worse situation.

Comment: Surely any problem that stops you can not be called small.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for something that would mean, "Out of the fire and into the frying pan." I suppose you could use that.

Comment: These aren't real as far as I know but their gist might help lead you to one that is: "forgetting the minus sign," "missing the extra point," (or rather "three-putting for a four" in England), or "forgetting/failing to hit the save button."

Comment: "missing the extra point" +1 Papa Poule! How timely and apt.

Answer (score 2):

**Well, there’s a venerable English proverb that warns, “*The Devil is in the detail*.”**

> The idiom "*the devil is in the detail*" refers to a catch or mysterious element hidden in the details, and derives from the earlier phrase "*God is in the detail*" expressing the idea that whatever one does should be done thoroughly; i.e. ***details are important.***
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil_is_in_the_detail)
>
> **And, the *wiseGEEK*, has this to say**:
>
> The slang term “*the devil is in the detail*” has a number of different senses. All of the meanings for the term boil down to the fact that ***it is often the small details of something which make it difficult or challenging. These details can prolong a task, or foil an otherwise straightforward dealing***. Like many proverbs which involve the devil, it is meant to sound a note of caution. It may also be used to excuse or explain the obfuscation of an otherwise very simple project or task.
>
> [**wiseGEEK.org**](http://www.wisegeek.org/what-does-the-devils-in-the-details-mean.htm)

Often this expression is used when a project has fallen short of what one would expect (*such as a poem whose themes and rhyme schemes are tight but whose rhythm is still off meter*) or as a reminder that paying attention to critical details enables the final product to achieve a desired level of "*quality*".

Answer (score 0):

In the same general area — though they are not precise matches for your desired expression — are:

- taking one's success for granted
- overreaching oneself
- biting off more than one can chew
- being over-confident
- becoming too complacent

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

Swam across a stormy ocean only to be held up by traffic two blocks from home.

Comment: This is not an idiomatic expression.